# Spring batch uses relational database to store job metadata

Tags: elasticsearch

I am aware of spring batch metadata tables are written to Relational database tables say MySQL,H2 etc. But my question is whether spring batch metadata tables can be written to elasticsearch . If so how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the [Spring Batch Extensions](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/10/spring-batch-releases-and-a-new-repository) module?  This module provides an ItemReader and an ItemWriter for interacting with Elasticsearch. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually my use case is to make distributed spring batch applications that relies on its localized database. However, I have achieved the first part of it i.e database localization for each of the spring batch application using H2 but it led to a new problem how to handle restart case. Lets say we submit a job to spring batch application X and it failed. When I submit same job for restart to another spring batch application say Y. It happens that JobOperator needs the job information that failed last which is missing in Y localized db hence restart fails.